# socket.io not sending events to others in room

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

So I'm trying to figure out what is going on with a very basic socket.io application. I'm testing this by having 2 different tabs that register as different users and trying to see if the other gets the events. Neither frontend recieves the others events, but the server does for sure receive the event correctly. My frontend is vue.js and I THINK I have the proxy setup correctly. I'm not sure why rooms 2 people connected to the same room wouldn't receive the events based on the documentation.

Edit: If I remove the .to for the roomId the message will get replicated ONLY to the user that sent the message :/ not sure if that means anything.

Edit2: It has something to do with the rabbitmq adapter not working for relaying the messages. By removing that middle ware everything works.

Node.js Server

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
const adapter = require('socket.io-amqp');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server,{
  path: '/socket'
});

io.adapter(adapter('amqp://localhost'));

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello World, Again</h1>')
});

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
  
  const query = socket.handshake.query;
  const userId = query['userId'] as string;
  const roomId = query['roomId'] as string;
  if(!userId || !roomId)
  { 
    console.log('failed to connect - userId or roomId is undefined');
    socket.disconnect(); 
    return;
  } 
  
  socket.join(roomId);
  console.log(`connection - user: ${userId}, room: ${roomId}`);

  socket.on('newValue',(e) => {
    socket.to(roomId).emit('newValue',{
      userId: userId,
      value: e.value
    });

    console.log(`roomId: ${roomId}, userId: ${userId}, value: ${e.value}`);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=> {
    socket.to(roomId).emit('userDisconnect',{
      userId: userId
    });

    console.log(`disconnect - user: ${userId}, room: ${roomId}`);
  });

  socket.to(roomId).emit('newUser',{
    userId
  });
});
 
const PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Vue.js View that manages the socket

```
<template>
  <div class="room">
    <div class="p-grid">
      <div class="p-col-12">
        <playing-card :value="selectedValue" class="center-card"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
      <div class="p-col-12">
        <value-selector @change="onValueChange"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import 'vue-router';
import { userStore } from '../store/index';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import ValueSelector from '../components/ValueSelector.vue';
import PlayingCard from '../components/PlayingCard.vue';

@Options({ 
  components: { 
    PlayingCard, ValueSelector
  }
})
export default class Room extends Vue {
  
  selectedValue = -1;
  private socket!: Socket | null;

  private closeSocket(): void {
    if(this.socket)
    {
      this.socket.close();
      this.socket = null;
    }
  }

  private configureSocket(): void {
    if(!this.socket)
    {
      this.socket = io({
        path: '/socket',
        reconnection: true,
        reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
        query: {
          roomId: this.$route.params.roomId as string,
          userId: userStore.getters.userId as string
        }
      });

      this.socket.on('newValue',(e)=>{
        console.log(e);
      });

      this.socket.onAny((eventName,e)=>{
        console.log(eventName);
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  }

  mounted(): void {
    this.configureSocket();
  }

  onValueChange(values: any) {
    this.selectedValue = values.newVal;
    if(this.socket)
    {
      this.socket.emit('newValue', {
        value: this.selectedValue
      });
    }
  }

  unmounted(): void {
    this.closeSocket();
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.center-card {
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/socket': {
          target: 'http://localhost:3000',
          changeOrigin: true,
          ws: true,
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Server Logs

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
listening on http://localhost:3000
connection - user: ls91m4il, room: 123, socketId: 86zN3g6maJu1z0OzAAAB
connection - user: pq68znqa, room: 123, socketId: xvKKzXhEbCrnz_l_AAAD
roomId: 123, userId: ls91m4il, socketId, 86zN3g6maJu1z0OzAAAB value: 5
roomId: 123, userId: pq68znqa, socketId, xvKKzXhEbCrnz_l_AAAD value: 13
```

No frontend logs get triggered for event responses for the onAny or on subscription with matching named events.

Comment: Get rid of the vue stuff its not relevant if your problem is not receiving messages. Put in some logs and figure out what is and isn't happening.  Watch the network tab to see if messages are received.

Comment: I mean vue.js is using a proxy ... I don't know if it is relevant or not. There are a lot of logs in the code. Message hits the server and then the clients don't receive any messages from there ... feel this comment was made without actually paying attention to what I said ...

Comment: The longer a post is the harder it is to read and understand what your actual problem is. In this case it sounds like you are not using the socket.io api properly. The first step in this case is to eliminate everything else and focus on getting that working. Then you can readd in the vue stuff.  On the way you may figure out what your actual problem is and be in a position to ask a question beyond "Why doesn't my code work?"

Answer (score 3):

First off, `socket.to(roomId).emit(...)` will send messages to every socket in the roomId EXCEPT for the client represented by `socket`.  If you want to send to all sockets in `roomId`, you would use `io.to(roomId).emit(...)`.  It wasn't clear to me if you wanted to send to ALL sockets or all sockets except the originator so I want to make sure you understand that aspect of things.

Things to assure yourself with debugging and logging that may shed some light on the issue:

1. Ensure that both clients connect to your server and stay connected.  Logging the actual `socket.id` on both the `connect` and `disconnect` events will give you good picture of that.
2. Ensure that both clients are requesting the same `roomId`.  If the `roomId` was different for each, then there would only ever be one socket in the `roomId` and `socket.to().emit()` would have nobody else to send to.
3. Ensure that the client sending the `newValue` message is not posting a form which then causes the page to reload and thus the old socket is disconnected and a new one created.  The logging in point #1 should make sure you don't see this happening.  I mention this mostly because this is a common mistake, though I don't see enough of your actual HTML page to know if this could be an issue for you or not.
4. Log every incoming message on your server.  Log, not only the message, but also the `socket.id` that it arrives from.  This will allow you to reconstruct the whole message flow.

Without all this data, we don't have any ability to pinpoint the problem.  This type of problem requires gathering data, then following leads until you can see more precisely what is and isn't happening.  If I had to hazard a guess, I'd wonder if you have a problem with either #1 or #2.

Comment: I was logging all that stuff except socketId, I've added it and still seeing the same thing. No reconnections, message goes down to emit newValue, none of the clients get it.  

Does socket.io not work with multiple browser tabs on the dev machine?

Comment: @ChaseRLewis - If you want us to be able to help you further, we need to see ALL those logs you say you've added.  Please add the code (including all the new `console.log()` statements) to your question and add the resulting logs you get in the console.  Socket.io works just fine with multiple browser tabs.

Comment: @ChaseRLewis - I don't see any client-side code that is specifically listening for the `newValue` message which is what your server is sending in the `socket.to().emit()`.  That would certainly explain why you don't receive it.  Are you relying on `this.socket.onAny(...)` for that?

Comment: I was relying onAny because newValue wasn't working. I have now added both into the code and neither is responding. I have also added the server logs requested. No frontend logs get triggered. Server side code shows the newValue on server is triggered.

Comment: @ChaseRLewis - I don't know.  I'd try sending some fixed message back to the client when you receive the `newValue` message on your server.  For example do `socket.emit('gotNewValue')` and see if your client can receive ANY message back directly from your server - not even involving rooms?  Register a specific listener for the `gotNewValue` message in your client.  You need to simplify to find something that works and then build back on top of that.  I'm not at all familiar with what you're doing with the proxy and the custom adapter so perhaps that plays into the issue too.

Comment: If I do that jfriend00 only the user who sent the message receives a response. That was mentioned in my first edit. I'm thinking it has something to do with the vue server, trying to get CORS worked out so I can connect to it directly and remove the proxy as a source of error.

Comment: @ChaseRLewis - Yes, I know that.  We're trying to see if your client can receive ANY message from the server.  If so, then we can build on that.  If not, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: Yeah other than that specific way, even connected DIRECTLY to the backend server I cannot get an emit to trigger the frontends even with io.emit('newValue');;

Comment: I found it has something to do with the rabbitmq adapter. I have got it working by removing that component for now.

Comment: @ChaseRLewis - OK, good now you have a specific source of the problem to look into and it looks like your regular socket.io code is not the cause.